# Android - Retrieve user's data after login

Tags: android

Suppose i have a database, in which i store some informations about some users, for example:

```
Username
Password
preferred songs
hobby
age
```

now I want to "split" these information so that in a `LoginActivity` the user can set his Username and password, and after the login the other informations are displayed in a second activity. 
I thinked to use Preferences for the `LoginActivity` in order to also remember the user's data in a second moment (with a function 'Remember Me'), but how can i do the retrieving of the other informations?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sqLite database for storing the above parameters and for second moment (with a function 'Remember Me')you can use SharedPreference for managing session between activity.